# Facebook customer Chat not showing on Joomla page

Tags: javascript, facebook, messenger

I have added code from messenger configurator to my page (just after opening body tag) - but the messenger window is not showing... - the code is visible when I inspect the page - I tried it in domain/test.html file and it worked just fine. Any ideas why that might happen? Already tried most of the common suggestions I could find on SO.

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            xfbml            : true,
            version          : 'v4.0'
          });
        };

        (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

      <!-- Your customer chat code -->
      <div class="fb-customerchat"
        attribution=setup_tool
        page_id="189127827929149"       minimised="false"    theme_color="#8cc63f"   logged_in_greeting="Witaj! Jak możemy Ci pomóc?"   logged_out_greeting="Witaj! Jak możemy Ci pomóc?">
      </div>
```

Comment: did you check out the browser console for warnings or errors? btw, be careful with parameters, it is "minimized", not "minimised". also, that parameter is outdated/deprecated according to the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin/#customization

Comment: thanks for the info about param - i copied it from SO. 
Yeah I checked console, there is no info about it :(

Comment: do not copy code from SO, copy from the original source instead. anyway, what about the dynamic source? did you check out the chat div in the browser dev tools? a test link would be a lot easier for us to help.

Comment: searching for the div with accurate ID made me think - as it appears I have some plugin FB to show liks, has same ID - when i turned it off chat started working just fine. Thanks for good suggestion and the help! :)

Comment: alright, please create an answer with this information and accept it, so others can easily find it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

searching for the div with accurate ID made me think - as it appears I had some plugin FB to show likes, that has same ID - when i turned it off chat started working just fine.